# How do I get all the neighbour-indices in a matrix without including negative values?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, rust

I'm struggling to find all direct neighbours for a given position (which is a `(usize, usize)`) in an `N` x `M` matrix.

The matrix provides a method `get(p: Position) -> Option<T>` where it does bounds checking and returns `None` if the position is out of range. This means an upper bound does not need to be checked, but a lower bound still needs to. That is, it does not underflow `0` in any direction.

My first attempt was to iterate over the slice `&[-1, 0, 1]` and use `checked_add`, but this does not work because `-1` is not a `usize`.

My next attempt was to subtract 1 from my position (both `x` and `y`) and then iterate over the slice `&[0, 1, 2]`, but that does not work the position `(0, _)` or `(_, 0)`.

I prepared a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=497f81f5c4a7c60a06eaf042ed2468da&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015), where one just can implement the one function. (I hope my tests are correct)

```
type Position = (usize, usize) //x, y

fn get_neighbours(p: Position) -> impl Iterator<Item = Position> {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

(`impl Iterator` can be replaced by `Vec` if necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `if` expressions to handle the special case that the coordinates are zero, e.g.

```
fn get_neighbours(p: Position) -> impl Iterator<Item = Position> {
    let m_range = if p.0 > 0 { p.0 - 1..p.0 + 2 } else { 0..2 };
    let n_range = if p.1 > 0 { p.1 - 1..p.1 + 2 } else { 0..2 };
    m_range
        .flat_map(move |m| n_range.clone().map(move |n| (m, n)))
        .filter(move |&q| p != q)
}
```

Comment: Hey @SvenMarnach I want to let you know, that 3 years later I'm still looking up this question frequently, because I always need this function :D thanks again for your answer!